# Docker build failed: tag invalid reference format (Gitlab CI)

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've created a repo in gitlab for a Dockerfile.
In the .gitlab-ci.yml i defined two stages: build and push to the registry.

This is the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker

stages:
    - build
    - push

build:
    stage: build
    script:
      - docker build --no-cache -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/debian9-cunit .

push:
    stage: push
    script:
      - docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/debian9-cunit
```

When I run the pipeline, the build stage fails saying:

> invalid argument "/debian9-cunit" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format

The same exact code (with only a different name after "/debian9-") works with no problem in another repo of a collegue. 
What can be the problem?

Comment: Seems the ${DOCKER_REGISTRY} variable is not replaced, perhaps the pipeline  is looking into system variables. could you try to add double quotes in the script section?

Comment: I tried both "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/debian9-cunit" and "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}"/debian9-cunit but the result is the same

Comment: Try replacing ${DOCKER_REGISTRY} with an actual existing repository. I agree with @M.Falzone, seems like that variable isn't set, and Docker is yelling because you can't start your tag with a slash.

Comment: is it possible that DOCKER_REGISTRY isn't setted up?
btw seems you want to use the gitlab.com registry, in that case, try with
"docker build --no-cache -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/debian-9-cunit ."

Comment: If I replace with ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/debian-9-cunit I get: "invalid argument "/federico/dk-debian9-cunit/debian9-cunit" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format"

Comment: @bluescores Which kind of actual existing repository? Sorry it's my firs time with CI and Docker

Comment: From your comment, CI_REGISTRY hasn't been replaced correctly but CI_PROJECT_PATH has been. Where are you running this pipeline? is gitlab.com or an hosted instance, is the registry active?

Comment: It's hosted internally in my company. I will ask to my tutor about the registry, I don't think I have access to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I didn't have a GitLab runner on my personal company profile. The other project was of a group that has a shared runner.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is having this issue in combination with Heroku-based applications (e.g. in Gitlab AutoDevOps) you might need to activate the GitLab container registry on your [GitLab installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html) and in [your project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html).