# GitLab pipeline is failing due to invalid docker build tag reference

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a GitLab pipe line for a Spring boot project with branch name as 'test-pipeline' as part of a POC. The pipeline is failing with below error. The tag reference has '/' character in the beginning. Not sure if this causing the issue.

```
Running before_script and script
00:03
 $ if [[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]]; then # collapsed multi-line command
 $ /build/build.sh
 Building Heroku-based application using gliderlabs/herokuish docker image...
 invalid reference format
 invalid reference format
 invalid argument "/test-pipeline:feec5e03aac2aa1968594056d67b9e43d2240e24" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
 See 'docker build --help'
```

Below is the gitlab-ci.yml.

```
image: maven:3.3-jdk-8
stages:
  - test
  - deploy
test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pwd
    - mvn clean
    - mvn compile
    - mvn test
  tags:
    - docker
```

GitLab version: 12.10.14
GitLab Runner version: 12.10.3

As the tag name is internally picked up by the pipeline not sure how to fix this.

Please help.

Comment: yeah, i think this `invalid argument "/test-pipeline:feec5e03aac2aa1968594056d67b9e43d2240e24" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format` refers to docker tag being invalid, so you'd need to strip `/` from the beginning of string which docker tag is based on.

Comment: @AnnaSlastnikova : I am not sure what the build is trying here, I mean why it is running docker build command and how it is getting the tag reference wrongly. Can it be the case some value is missing in front of the tag. For instance  "xyz/test-pipeline:feec5e03aac2aa1968594056d67b9e43d2240e24". May be xyz is is user name or something else.

Comment: it may be not user name but docker registry. The first snippet of code - do you know where it's running? From it it looks like it's some script on a gitlab runner which looks like heroku setup, sorry I'm not exactly familiar with heroku on gitlab but might this is going to be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729959/6635320 ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @AnnaSlastnikova. I got the root cause of the issue. The gitlab-ci.yml file name is missing '.' in the begining, due to this default file is being picked up. Hence causing the issues. This is resolved after the changing the name.

Answer (score 1):

I got the root cause of the issue. The gitlab-ci.yml file name is missing '.' in the begining, due to this default file is being picked up. Hence causing the issues. This is resolved after the changing the name to .gitlab-ci.yml.